# Text highlighting in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in HTML with jquery.

I want to make a webpage to highlight some text lines (line nos 15, 22, 32) in that page at a time. This can be done by left click in mouse and drag that line, so that the text line is selected with blue background.

I am able to get the selected lines as follows using jquery,

```
    function getText() {
        var text = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {
            text = window.getSelection().toString();
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            text = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        console.log('text-----------'+text)
    }
```

When I am clicking other line, first selected line was disappears. I need that line also be available. (In MSword, we can hold ctrl and drag the lines and it will be available)

For multiple selection, I know there is more plugins available in web. But I am looking for doing this selection using Javascript or jquery.

This is what I am looking for to do in my page, want to select texts and get them in my javascript function.

[image]

How may we do this?

Comment: this question is not clear. Can you try and explain clearer?

Comment: You can style selected text using `::selection ` pseudo class.

Comment: `For multiple selection` What is your final goal? Just style? Or you want that you could `copy` the selection texts?

Comment: @MoshFeu, Yes I want to copy that texts.

Comment: And if you will do `paste` it will paste all the texts together?

Comment: Copying requires Flash for some reason, might not work on Firefox.

Comment: Ok, is there possible to mark the background color of the texts in webpage?

Comment: @MoshFeu, thats fine. is that possible?

Comment: so you copied this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text changed the function name and want us to do the work?

Comment: @caramba he wants to do this but with multiple selection.

Comment: @MoshFeu I'm just trying to say that he didn't try anything really showing any effort how he could solve the "multy-selection" part..

Comment: @caramba, do you know I didn't do anything? mind your words, especially over the web. If you dont know what to do, then just leave it. This is what the difference between poor or ordinary developers like you and complete professionals. Complete professionals knows well what happened in background. You proved it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is combined of some issues.

1. Get the selection text
2. Mark it.
3. Copy to clipboard

**It's not the full solution but there are all the parts.**

So:

```js
var output = '';
$('#test').mouseup(function () {
    output += getSelectedText();
    highlightSelected();
    copyOutput();
    $('#result').html(output);
});

function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}

function highlightSelected() {
    var SelRange;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        SelRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        SelRange = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    } else if (document.selection) {
        SelRange = document.selection.createRange();
    }

    if (SelRange.pasteHTML) {
        SelRange.pasteHTML('<span class="hilited1">' + SelRange.text + '</span>');
    }
    else {
        var newNode = $('<span class="hilited1" />')[0];
        SelRange.surroundContents(newNode);
    }
}

function copyOutput() {
    var emailLink = document.querySelector('#result');
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(emailLink);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }

    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
}

.hilited1 {
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">I am working in HTML with jquery.
  I want to make a webpage to highlight some text lines (line nos 15, 22, 32) in that page at a time. This can be done by left click in mouse and drag that line, so that the text line is selected with blue background.
I am able to get the selected lines as follows using jquery,
</div>
<hr />
<div id="result"></div>
<hr />
<textarea placeholder="Try to paste here"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mosh.This looks similar. I got some ideas to get some thoughts from your help. My requirement is bit different. Anyway, this is very much helpful for me.

Comment: I glad to hear! Good luck!

Comment: If I am having two <p> tag inside the div id test, then this highlight doesn't works. Can we get this? also can we remove the bit of  content from the selected content. For example, If initially I selected 100 chars wrongly, can we change it to 80 chars by not highlighting the remaining 20 chars by aain select them.

Comment: Mosh, Can you give some suggestions on my above comment